# swift 4 - HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber deprecated

Tags: swift, deprecated, ios11, swift4, homekit

I want to read information of an accessory, typed `HMAccessory`, such as Serial number (`HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber`), manufacturer (`HMCharacteristicTypeManufacturer`), model (`HMCharacteristicTypeModel`) but they all are deprecated in iOS11, according to this Apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmcharacteristic/characteristic_types).

I know I can instead use the `characteristicType` string directly, like below:

`HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber` -> `00000030-0000-1000-8000-0026BB765291`

`HMCharacteristicTypeManufacturer` -> `00000020-0000-1000-8000-0026BB765291`

`HMCharacteristicTypeModel`-> `00000021-0000-1000-8000-0026BB765291`

But that just makes my code "unconventional", ugly.

Do you know the replacements for the characteristic types of serial number, manufacturer and model? I have searched for hours but still no clues.

Comment: My assumption on these being deprecated is not just that the Characteristic -> UUID mapping will disappear in the future, but that asking for those UUIDs would no longer return valid results. I don't have any answer yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, as of iOS 11.0, those `characteristicType`constants have been deprecated. Access to manufacturer, model, and firmware version info is now obtained through the newer `HMAccessory` properties `manufacturer`, `model`, and `firmwareVersion`.

For example:

```
print("Manufacturer: \(accessory.manufacturer)")
print("Model: \(accessory.model)")
print("Firmware Version: \(accessory.firmwareVersion)")
```

However, as far as I can see, while `HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber` has also been deprecated, there isn't any property on `HMAccessory` to access this info so far.

Comment: Any Apple documentation or links available as to why no properties have been added to access "HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber" ?