# Any alternative for HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, homekit

> `'HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber'` was deprecated in iOS 11.0 : No longer supported

Is there any other way we can fetch the serial number of the device?

Is there any new API provided to fetch the SerialNumber?

[AppleDoc.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmcharacteristictypeserialnumber?language=objc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now iOS 11.0, characteristicTypeconstants have been deprecated. Access to manufacturer, model, and firmware version info, Now obtained through the newer `HMAccessory` properties `manufacturer`, `model`, and `firmwareVersion`. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558500/swift-4-hmcharacteristictypeserialnumber-deprecated)

For example:

```
print("Manufacturer: \(accessory.manufacturer)")
print("Model: \(accessory.model)")
print("Firmware Version: \(accessory.firmwareVersion)")
```